# How can I debug .gitignore file handling?

Tags: windows, git

I’m having lots of trouble convincing git to ignore files in my project.

Basically, sometimes it works, sometimes it just *seems* to ignore the .gitignore file for no obvious reason. (By “seems” I mean that there are patterns in it that look as if they should exclude something, but that something is not excluded.)

There’s a 'git check-ignore' command, but it only says which pattern matched a file. But I can’t find any option to make it say which patterns it’s found and where, nor why those patterns do *not* match a file.

**Is there a way to do this kind of debugging?**

P.S. There is a single issue which I did find, and I’m mentioning it here in case it helps others:

I was adding patterns using “`echo pattern >> .gitignore`”, which at least on my system results in spaces at the of the line (i.e., everything between “`echo`” and “`>>`” is echoed in the file, except for the first space character after “echo”).

Git does *not* trim those spaces when matching patterns, so for the command above it wouldn’t match a file named “`pattern`” but it would match “`pattern{space}`”.

I think most of my issues stem from this. Those extra spaces are hard to notice, so I’d still like a debug command that makes sure I notice them, if there is one.

**Edit #1:**
Yes, I did try `-v`. For example:

```
> mkdir test
> touch test/file.txt
> echo test >> .gitignore
> git check-ignore -v test/file.txt
```

(nothing is printed)

```
> echo test>> .gitignore
> git check-ignore -v test/cuc.txt
.gitignore:8:test       test/cuc.txt
```

Note the extra space in the first `echo` line, which makes it enter “test[space]” as a pattern. As I mentioned, “check-ignore” tells you what matched, but it doesn’t tell you what didn’t nor why.

Comment: Did you do a `git check-ignore -v`?

Comment: VonC: Yes, I did. For example:

`>mkdir test`
`>touch test/file.txt`
`>echo test >> .gitignore`
`>git check-ignore -v test/file.txt`
(nothing is printed)
`>echo test>> .gitignore`
`>git check-ignore -v test/cuc.txt`
`.gitignore:8:test       test/cuc.txt`

(Note the extra space in the extra `echo` line. Sorry, I don’t know how to put newlines comments.)

Comment: Note: to ignore a all folder, that would rather be `touch test/ >> .gitignore` (trailing space of no trailing space)

Comment: You’re probably right, this was just a simple example. (And it does what I wanted when I don't put the extra space.)

Comment: By the way, what version of git are you using?

Comment: It says "git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0".

Comment: Can you try with the latest realease? (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411). Uncompress the archive where you want: no need to modify your current git: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411/PortableGit-1.9.2-preview20140411.7z

Comment: I know this is 2 years old, but I ran into this issue recently and fixed it by setting the .gitignore encoding to UTF-8 (Notepad++ can do this)